# How to position matplotlib text relative to graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, matplotlib, visualization

I'm trying to position text on a matplotlib plot, but I want to be able to have the text remain relative to the position on the graph.

It can be seen that the desired position of the text is central to the section that it's representing (see image).

I currently have a couple of `offset` values that I'm using to do this, but if I change the x range that I'm operating over or the function these values no longer apply.

I would like to have a general way of positioning the text so that regardless of the function used the text will be central and sensibly positioned.

By sensibly positioned I mean that there should be a gap between $\delta x$ and the horizontal line representing it. And the gap between $\delta y$ should be equal to that of $\delta x$

## Output

[image]

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
plt.style.use('ggplot')

matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.unicode'] = True

###############################################################################

def f(x):
    return x**3

def tri(x1, x2, f):
    """input of two x coordinates and function, create and label a triangle to
    represent finding the gradient
    """

    color = "green"
    lw = 3

    # Plot the triangle beneath the curve
    plt.plot([x1, x2], [f(x1), f(x1)], color=color, linewidth=lw)
    plt.plot([x2, x2], [f(x1), f(x2)], color=color, linewidth=lw)

    fontSz = 45

    # TODO: I'M NOT SURE HOW TO PLACE THE FONT SO THAT IF I CHANGE THE FUNCTION
    # OR FONT SIZE THE FONT IS PLACED IN THE SAME POSITION RELATIVELY

    offset1 = 0.5  # < < < These!
    offset2 = 0.05 # < < <

    dx_x_place = ((x1) + (x2))/2
    dx_y_place = f(x1) - offset1

    dy_x_place = x2 + offset2
    dy_y_place = (f(x1) + f(x2))/2

    # annotate delta x
    plt.text(
        dx_x_place,
        dx_y_place,
        r'$\delta x$',
        horizontalalignment='center',
        verticalalignment='top',
        fontsize=fontSz,
        color='black'
    )

    # Annotate delta y
    plt.text(
        dy_x_place,
        dy_y_place,
        r'$\delta y$',
        horizontalalignment='left',
        verticalalignment='center',
        fontsize=fontSz,
        color='black'
    )

###############################################################################

# global variables
X_DOMAIN = [-1,4]
X_DENSITY = 300
LINEWIDTH = 3


x = np.linspace(X_DOMAIN[0], X_DOMAIN[1], X_DENSITY)
y = f(x)

# Just put some axis on the graph
# http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline
plt.axhline(linewidth = 1, color="grey")
plt.axvline(linewidth = 1, color="grey")

# create triangle to represent delta x,y
tri(2, 3, f)

plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=LINEWIDTH)
plt.show()
```

## System that I'm using

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

## Python version that I'm using

```
3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

## Matplotlib version

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.__version__
Out[37]: '1.5.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to keep a fixed offset, not in data-coordinates but in either axis-coordinates or display coordinates (i.e. pixels).  Since the transforms are a bit cumbersome to work with I would recommend you to look at [the transform documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) or [the second example here](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Transformations.html).  However I believe the documentation, especially the `inverted()`-function might be helpful.  The docs says: *You can use the inverted() method to create a transform which will take you from display to data coordinates*, with the example from the doc:

```
In [1]: inv = ax.transData.inverted()
In [2]: inv.transform((335.175,  247.))
Out[3]: array([ 5.,  0.])
```

This means that you can get the x-offset in data-coordinates with `inv.transform(10, 0)`, and it should return `array([xoffset_corresponding_to_10pixels, 0])`.  Do the same for the y-offset.  You probably have to update the offset-value every time you zoom though...  I know this is not a complete answer, but hopefully it will help you get started.

Comment: it does not solve the question but says 'please look in the docs'

Comment: I came across this question because I wanted to place text relative to the axes and not the data coordinates - anyway I also found this link which might be helpful to anyone with that same challenge: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.09-text-and-annotation.html